# Is there anything wrong with proof of $\left|AB/A\right|=\left|B/(A\cap B)\right|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is just a set-theoric analogue of 2nd Isomorphism Theorem:

> (2nd Isomorphism Theorem) Let $G$ be a group and $A\triangleleft G, B\le G$. Then $AB/A$ and $B/(A\cap B)$ are isomorphic as groups.
> Claim: Let $G$ be a group and $A,B\le G$, then $\left|AB/A\right|=\left|B/(A\cap B)\right|$

I asked this to my abstract algebra professor, and he said no. But this seems to me to be true after a little more refinement of the proof after class.

There's no way I'm better at math than a professor, so there must be a problem in my proof process. Could you tell me where the lack of logic is? Any help would be appreciated.

(My proof)

I approached it with right cosets, because its cardinality is exactly same with left cosets. (Professor gave me this approach!) So from now on, it will be a little confused, but I'll use this notation. (Please let me know if you have any good notation!) $AB/A=\{Aab\mid a\in A, b\in B\}=\{Ab\mid b\in B\}, B/(A\cap B)=\{(A\cap B)b\mid b\in B\}$.

Let a map(not homomorphism!) $\psi:AB/A\to B/(A\cap B)$ as $\psi: Ab \mapsto (A\cap B)b$. If $Ab=Ac$, then $\exists a\in A\text{ s.t. }cb^{-1}=a$. $a\in A\cap B$, so $c=ab\in(A\cap B)b$, so $(A\cap B)b=(A\cap B)c$. It means $\psi(Ab)=\psi(Ac)$, which makes $\psi$ a well-defined map.

As set, $\psi(Ab)=(A\cap B)b\subseteq Ab$. If $\psi(Ab)=\psi(Ac)$, then $Ab\cap Ac\supseteq\psi(Ab)\cap\psi(Ac)\neq\emptyset$. $Ab\cap Ac\ne\emptyset$, so $Ab=Ac$. $\psi$ is injection, and $\psi$ is trivially surjection.

So, there exists well-defined bijection $\psi$ between $AB/A$ and $B/(A\cap B)$, this means my claim is true. QED.

+) I noticed [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3882210/lemma-used-to-prove-lefthk-right-frac-lefth-right-leftk-right-lefth), which makes my claim true in finite case, but the index or size of group $A,B$ could be infinite. In many cases, the approach is different when finite case and infinite case, so I could not be sure that my proof or claim was true with that post alone.

Comment: There is an issue here, which is that you do not know if $AB$ is a subgroup; because $AB$ is not necessarily a subgroup, it is not clear that the number of left cosets is the same as the  number of right cosets: the usual argument uses that $gA$ corresponds to $Ag^{-1}$, but here, the coset of $ab$ would "correspond" to the coset of $b^{-1}a^{-1}$... which is in $BA$, but not necessarily in $AB$ (since $AB$ is a subgroup if and only if $AB=BA$).

Comment: Oh, I missed it. Thanks @ArturoMagidin! Then, is it true when restrict these cosets are always right coset?

Comment: The result is false as stated, if $AB/A$ means left cosets of $A$ represented by elements of $AB$. Consider $G=S_3$, $A=\{1,(12)\}$, $B=\{1,(13)\}$. Then $AB=\{1,(12),(13),(132)\}$ (composing right-to-left), and so the left cosets are $1A = (12)A$, $(13)A$, and $(132)A$. Note that $(13)A\neq (132)A$, since $(132)^{-1}(13) = (123)(13) = (23)\notin A$. So $|AB/A|=3$. But $A\cap B=\{1\}$, and $B/(A\cap B)$ has two elements.

Comment: For right cosets, cosets of $A$ represented by elements of $AB$ are the same as cosets of $A$ represented by elements of $B$; that is, $\{Aab\mid a\in A, b\in B\} = \{Ab\mid b\in B\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that you need to be careful with your cosets, because by dropping the assumption that $A$ is normal, you also lose the conclusion that $AB$ is a subgroup (this may or may not hold when neither subgroup normalizes the other). As such, you *do* need to distinguish between left and right cosets, as for an arbitrary subset $S$ of $G$, and subgroup $K$, the sets
$$\{sK\mid s\in S\}\quad\text{and}\quad\{Ks\mid s\in S\}$$
need not have the same cardinality. For example, with $G=S_3$, $K=\{e,(12)\}$, and $S=\{e, (12),(13),(132)\}$, we get three left cosets, $eK=(13)K$, $(13)K$, and $(132)K$ (I compose permutations right-to-left), and we get two right cosets,
$Ke=K(12)$ and $K(13)=K(132)$.

I would interpret $AB/A$ to be the set of **left** cosets of $A$ represented by elements of $AB$. In that interpretation, the claimed equality may fail. With $G=S_3$, $A=\{e,(12)\}$, and $B=\{e,(13)\}$, we get as above that $AB/A$ has three elements, while $B/(A\cap B)$ has two.

If we look at *right* cosets, though, the equality holds. As noted,
$$\{Aab\mid a\in A, b\in B\} = \{Ab\mid b\in B\}.$$
Now note that
$$\begin{align*}
Ab=Ab' &\iff b'b^{-1}\in A\\
&\iff b'b^{-1}\in A\cap B\\
&\iff (A\cap B)b = (A\cap B)b'
\end{align*}$$
showing the map $Ab\longmapsto (A\cap B)b$ is well defined and injective, and it is trivially surjective.

A similar argument shows that $BA/A$ (the left cosets represented by elements of the set $BA$) is in bijective correspondence with $B/(A\cap B)$ (left cosets again, though here you do get a bijection with right cosets of $A\cap B$ in $B$).